# XPath Selector with conditional calculated by JSON values

Tags: xpath

Is there a way to define an XPath selector that uses a conditional operating on multiple values from the JSON I'm selecting from?

Consider the following example JSON:

```
{
    "values": [
        //previous entries
        {
            "value" : "50",
            "date" : "29-11-2018"
        },      {
            "value" : "100",
            "date" : "30-11-2018"
        },      {
            "value" : "150",
            "date" : "1-12-2018"
        },
        //following entries
    ]
}
```

Say, I wanted to select only the value for the last day of any month (for the sake of the example ignore Dec to Jan). My idea would be to select value if *month-in-date t1 - month-in-date t0 > 0*

Is there a syntax to calculate this condition with XPath?

Comment: XPath is typically used for traversing XML. Do you have some mechanism at your disposal that allows you to evaluate XPath on JSON? If so, what is it?

Comment: Paul is right. For the sake of the question, we can assume working with an XML file of a similar structure though.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to this link, [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) is

> [...] a language for addressing parts of an XML document, designed to be used by both XSLT and XPointer.

**But you want to address the JSON format...**
Luckily, there is a `C#` library implementing an XPath variant on CodeProject: [JUST - JSON Under Simple Transformation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187172/%2fArticles%2f1187172%2fJUST-JSON-Under-Simple-Transformation), an XSLT version for JSON which, or course, includes XPath functionality.

> JUST stands for JSON Under Simple Transformation.XSLT is a very popular way of transforming XML documents using a simple transformation language.
>   More and more applications are now using JSON as a data format because it is much simpler and less bulkier than XML.
>   However, there isn't a very easy way to transforming JSON documents.
>   I have created a library in .NET which enables the transformation of JSON documents using very a simple transformation language.
>   This is an attempt to create an XSLT parallel for JSON.

So a part of this package implements XPath-1.0(?) functionality.
Isolate this part, or use the whole package.

---

> My idea would be to select value `if month-in-date t1 - month-in-date t0 > 0`

An approach to a (partial) solution for this may look like this (I couldn't test and finish this, but you should get the idea.):

```
{
  "result": { "#ifcondition(#valueof($.values.date),condition,#valueof($.values.value),fail)" }
}
```